# Euler's formula

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I used Euler's formula to for $e^i\theta$ to derive the trig functions for $cos(\theta + \omega)$ and $sin(\theta+\omega)$?  Do I need to add something to the exponent of $e$ in order for this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Hint

$$e^{i(\theta+\omega)}=e^{i\theta}\cdot e^{i\omega}$$Then equate the real and imaginary parts